# "В сотрудничестве" и "при сотрудничестве"

Tags: стилистика

Чем отличается "в сотрудничестве" от "при сотрудничестве"?
Необходим ли предлог "с" после "при сотрудничестве"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"В сотрудничестве" предполагает совместное участие в проекте на равных ролях, а "при сотрудничестве" говорит, скорее, о помощи в работе.

(1) Она в ту же зиму написала роман «Rose et Blanche» в сотрудничестве с одним из своих земляков, со своим приятелем Жюлем Сандо.
Некрасову пришла мысль написать роман во французском вкусе, в сотрудничестве со мной и с Григоровичем.

(2) Феодальная система передает суд в руки сеньора, по уполномочию которого его заместитель судит обвиняемого при сотрудничестве определенного числа равных последнему по званию людей.

Answer (score 3):

По-моему, у этих сочетаний абсолютно разное значение и в предложении 2, приведенном Софией (*Феодальная система передает суд в руки сеньора, по уполномочию которого его заместитель судит обвиняемого **при** сотрудничестве определенного числа равных последнему по званию людей*), ошибка. Следовало написать "при участии".

(1) В значении "мы сделали это вместе" употребляется только "в сотрудничестве".

*Работы ведутся в сотрудничестве с немецкими поставщиками*.

(2) "При сотрудничестве" означает "сотрудничая с кем-то", "в процессе сотрудничества" и др.

*При сотрудничестве с нами вы получаете качественное фото* (сотрудничая с нами, вы...)

*Обман при сотрудничестве* (обман в процессе сотрудничества).

Но это мое субъективное мнение. В словарях ни подтверждения, ни опровержения не нашла.